# Variável this.variavel não carrega as informações para pesquisa, porém para listagem carregou

Tags: c#, classes

O código está disponível em:[GitHub](https://github.com/REBECANONATO/ControleNutricionista)

Eu tenho a Classe Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ControleClienteService controleCliente = new ControleClienteService();
            controleCliente.CarregarCliente();
            ControleConsultaService controleConsulta = new ControleConsultaService();
            controleConsulta.CarregarConsulta();



    Console.WriteLine("==== Lista de Clientes ====");
                            Console.WriteLine(controleCliente.Listar());
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
}
```

Quando eu Chamo o `controleCliente.Listar()`, ele traz as informações.

Classe Cliente:

```
public class ControleClienteService
    {
        private List<Cliente> Clientes;

        public bool CadastrarCliente(int qtdCliente, string nome, string endereco, string telefones, string email, string dataNascimento)
        {
            try
            {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente
                {
                    Id = qtdCliente,
                    Nome = nome,
                    Endereco = endereco,
                    Telefones = telefones,
                    Email = email,
                    DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(dataNascimento)
                };

                this.Clientes.Add(cliente);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public Cliente BuscarClienteId(int id)
        {
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            if (this.Clientes != null)
            {
                cliente = this.Clientes.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return cliente;

        }

        public bool CarregarCliente()
        {
            MClientes mClientes = new MClientes();
            this.Clientes = mClientes.PreencheClientes();
            return true;
        }

        public string Listar()
        {
            string retorno = "";
            foreach (Cliente C in this.Clientes)
            {
                retorno += C.Id.ToString() + "\n";
                retorno += C.Nome.ToString() + "\n";
                retorno += C.DataNascimento.ToString() + "\n";
                retorno += C.Telefones.ToString() + "\n";
                retorno += C.Endereco.ToString() + "\n";
                retorno += " \n";
            }
            return retorno;
        }
```

Classe Consulta:

```
public class MConsultas
    {
        List<Consulta> ConsultasClientes = new List<Consulta>();
        ControleClienteService ControleCliente = new ControleClienteService();
        ControleRestricaoAlimentarService RestricaoAlimentar = new ControleRestricaoAlimentarService();
        public List<Consulta> PreencheConsultas()
        {
            Consulta consulta = new Consulta
            {
                Id = 23,
                Cliente = ControleCliente.BuscarClienteId(23),
                RestricoesAlimentares = RestricaoAlimentar.BuscarRestricaoAlimentarId(23),
                Hora = Convert.ToDateTime("12:00"),
                Peso = 67,
                PercenteGordura = 34,
                Data = Convert.ToDateTime("19/12/2019")
            };
            // Adicionar na Lista
            ConsultasClientes.Add(consulta);

            return ConsultasClientes;
        }
    }
```

Quando chega na parte de chamar `Cliente = ControleCliente.BuscarClienteId(23),` A classe de Cliente está vazia, não contém os valores.
O `controleConsulta.CarregarConsulta();` Deveria trazer o Cliente, porém, sempre o Cliente no código está NULL.

**Como consigo acessar o Cliente, a partir da classe consulta, igual eu acesso a partir da classe Main?**

Comment: A propriedade `Clientes` está preenchida?

Comment: Sim, eu carrego ela em `ControleClienteService controleCliente = new ControleClienteService();
            controleCliente.CarregarCliente();`
Tanto que em `Console.WriteLine(controleCliente.Listar());`Funciona.

Porém, queria um jeito onde, em `Cliente = ControleCliente.BuscarClienteId(23),`Também funcionasse.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi do deu código, não existe construtor para o `ControleClienteService` e você não tá executando o `CarregarCliente()`  no `MConsultas`. Sendo assim, dentro da inicialização `new Consulta`, onde você executa o `BuscarClienteId(23)`, a lista `Clientes` está vazia, por isso ela só está returnando nulo...

Comment: Como fazer o Construtor para o `ControleClienteService`?

Comment: Basta você criar um método `public NomeDaClasse()`, que ele já associa com construtor. Você pode pegar mais detalhes [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)

Comment: Vou tentar fazer aqui.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar deu certo, se quiser coloca como resposta. Para eu marcar.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Como a resposta abaixo foi aceita (marcada com ✔️) isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema, basicamente, é que a lista de `Clientes` nunca era iniciada, para isso, basta criar um novo contrutor na classe `ControleClienteService`, que execute o método `CarregarCliente()`. Isso deve resolver o seu problema.